# How does this particular recursive CTE query work?

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression

I know that it's a simple code, yet it's confusing the heck out of me :(

```
WITH RECURSIVE odd_no (sr_no, n) AS
(
SELECT 1, 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT sr_no+1, n+2 from odd_no where sr_no < 5
)
SELECT * FROM odd_no;
```

This is the result we get when we run the query:

> sr_no  n
>
> 1   1
>
> 2   3
>
> 3   5
>
> 4   7
>
> 5   9

The query has two sub-queries.

### Following is how I imagine how the iterations should run

1st iteration-------------------------------------------------------------------

The first sub-query just returns 1 row:

> sr_no  n
>
> 1   1

I have no questions there.

2nd iteration-------------------------------------------------------------------

From here on, the 2nd sub-query comes into play. The query has a `where` clause checking the condition `sr_no < 5`. It finds **1 row** that satisfies the condition. And then, based on that 1 row, it adds another row and now we have this result:

> sr_no  n
>
> 1   1
>
> 2   3

No questions there either.

3rd iteration-------------------------------------------------------------------

*This is where the confusion begins.* In the 3rd iteration, the where clause checks the condition `sr_no < 5`. But unlike before, now **2 rows** satisfies the condition. And since `UNION ALL` allows for duplicate entries, this is how I **think** the output should have been.

> sr_no  n
>
> 1   1
>
> 2   3
>
> 2   3
>
> 3   5

But that is not the output we actually get when we run that query.

**Same confusion for the rest of the iterations. Duplicate entries should be piling up but it's clearly not what happens.**

I am probably thinking wrong about how the iterations work. I'd love for someone to clear it for me. Greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Edit question to include results as text. Jumping between 5 pages to answer a question is a high bar.

Comment: *But unlike before, now 2 rows satisfies the condition.* **NO**. Only the rows which were added to CTE rowset on the previous step are considered, all rows collected previously are ignored. So only one row which was added on 2nd iteration satisfies the condition.

Comment: Thank you Akina for clearing it up for me! That makes much more sense now :D